# Not all the groups are visible in Telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm using `chat.megagroup==true`
it is not showing all the channels (in `m==1`),
and it's also have issues like sometimes group A and group B is shown, sometimes either A or B is shown, sometimes group C is shown, 
don't know why it's happening without even changing anything in the code.

The script is overall working fine but the only issue is that I'm not having the groups sometimes, that are needed to use.

```
result = client(GetDialogsRequest(
             offset_date=last_date,
             offset_id=0,
             offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(),
             limit=chunk_size,
             hash = 0))

chats.extend(result.chats)
dialogs = client.get_dialogs()

m = input("1: For only permitted groups \n2: For all groups\n")
if m=='1':
    for chat in chats:
        try:
            if chat.megagroup == True:
                groups.append(chat)
        except:
            continue
elif m=='2':
    for i in dialogs:
        try:
            i.entity.status
        except:
            groups.append(i)
            continue
```

In `m==2`, all the groups are shown.
Can you please guide what I'm doing wrong or it's something else?

Answer (score 5):

`GetDialogsRequest` is a raw request and Telegram has a maximum limit of 100 for it. You should not use it, and you should always prefer to use `client.get_dialogs()`. You can check if it's a group with `dialog.is_group`, and a channel with `dialog.is_channel`. So, for megagroups:

```
if dialog.is_group and dialog.is_channel:
    # it's a megagroup (= supergroup)
```

The attributes can be found in the documentation at https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.dialog.Dialog.